# Different CSS files for different Media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is there a way to have an HTML file use a different stylesheet based on the media properties? I know that the `link` method takes a media type, but all the references I find only indicate the media type, not an extended query. I'm also unsure of how it would ensure only one is selected, and which one.

Basically in my current CSS file I have a media section like this (simplified just for reference):

```
@media (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  specific-media-rules
}
```

What I'd like is that instead of having this section and a very similar section for other media is to serve two distinct files.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes. An example could be the following: you want to use a different CSS file depending on the screen width (one for phones, one for small tablets) and you could do so like such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 140px) and (max-width: 380px)' href="phone.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 381px) and (max-width: 700px)' href="tablet.css"/>
```

**Note however**, that you need to make sure the requirements for each stylesheet won't ever be the same, as if they are (say if both stylesheets above had the same min-width and max-width) **both would be applied**.

Comment: How does it decide which one to pick if multiple match?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, it doesn't pick one *or* the other, it applies each stylesheet dependent on whether the media query happens to match. If multiple stylesheets apply, the cascade works as per usual.

Comment: Okay, I guess if I have two of them I can just use "Not" of the first ones query.

Comment: Or, just be sure to have not-overlapping rules (if possibile) :)

Comment: Or, 8 years later, you can have most of the rules in your base mobile media query, and then override them at various increasing size media queries. The thought is that tablets and desktop would have faster bandwidth to download, and as well more powerful systems/cpu's to process more styles and can handle the duplicates, vs a mobile phone which is the leanest of all three basic device sizes. The only caveat is TV screen browsers, they don't have the most powerful processing systems in many cases - not compared to a desktop computer.