# how can use a css reference dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

i am working on a react page, its css like as following:

```
@import "../../node_modules/toolbar/src/scss/index.scss";  
@import "../../node_modules/window/src/scss/index.scss";  

body {height: 100%;   
      position: fixed;   
      width: 100%;   
      user-select: none;  
      -webkit-user-select: none; }
....
```

recently i face a requirement:
**if the monitor resolution  changed, i need to refer some other css files to instead the old on**,  e.g. the Pseudocode should be like :

```
if(resolutionChanged){
    @import "../../node_modules/toolbar/src/scss/index.scss";  
    @import "../../node_modules/window/src/scss/index.scss";
}else{
    @import "../../node_modules/toolbar/src/scss/index2.scss";  
    @import "../../node_modules/window/src/scss/index2.scss";
}     
    body {height: 100%;   
          position: fixed;   
          width: 100%;   
          user-select: none;  
          -webkit-user-select: none; }
    ....
```

how can i achieve this Pseudocode in CSS or JS?

Comment: You can use css @media queries to define set or dub - sets of rules according to certain conditions.  See: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

Comment: Is this what you look for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138674/different-css-files-for-different-media-queries

Comment: Please write your posts in standard international English. Capitalize the first word of sentences. Capitalize the word "I".

Comment: it works, thanks Brian Peacock.

Answer (score 0):

you can't write such `if` statement in scss files, scss doesn't support it, you can use `@if`, but it doesn't support `js variable`.

but you can import different scss file in your `js file`. So you should import your scss file in your js file.

and remember, if you use webpack, you should use `require ensure` not `import your scss files` directly. Because when webpack bundle your code, it will not run your code, so it doesn't know the value of `resolutionChanged`.

you can find [require.ensure doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html) here

Comment: But I am in react.js, how can i refer the css file in jsx side?

Comment: just like this: `import styles from app.scss`