# Downscaling page for retina without loss of quality (blurry on Chrome)

Tags: html, css, safari, responsive-images

I noticed that when using CSS to resize a lossless `png` file (for normal/Retina purposes), on latest Chrome, (54.x at the time of writing), the result is blurry. [image: blurry]

When adding the following rule to the img tags

```
img {
   image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

Then the result is better:

[image: crispier]

The problem : Safari's engine renders this quite differently (much worse)

[image: safari]

My questions

1. how can I resize a lossless PNG without having quality problems?
2. if resizing always causes issues, what's the alternative to handle Higher-DPI monitors? (support for https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/ ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I opted for using srcset to do pure responsive images:

```
            <img
                    src="./img/logo.png"
                    srcset="./img/logo.png 1x,
                        ./img/logo@2x.png 2x"
            >
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use @media CSS to change the URL of the image. Using an image editing software to change the size of the images so the browser doesn't have to handle scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Use media query for high resolution display like:

```
@media
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.6/2),
(min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3),
(min-resolution: 1.3dppx) {
   /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```

For reference: http://brettjankord.com/2012/11/28/cross-browser-retinahigh-resolution-media-queries/

Comment: Would that mean the user is going to download two versions of the same image, one normal and one high resolution one?

Comment: Yes. In css rules put normal resolution image and inside media query add same rule with hi def image.

Comment: That's not optimal for web performance, two images will be downloaded but only one used...

Comment: Or you can use media query in head section to load different  css file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138674/different-css-files-for-different-media-queries

Answer (score 0):

use HTML  
srcset Attribute

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
  <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

and with adobe ps proses the image