# I want to load CSS file by Javascript according to screen size

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to load CSS file according to size of screen.

for example if width of screen is less than 576px than we have to load xs_0.css vice versa

```
<script>
    if (window.innerWidth < 576) {
        let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
        let link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.type = 'text/css';
        link.href = 'xs_0/style.css';
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Why? you can define different css logic for different screen sizes within one css file https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: I wanted complete changes if i use media query it becomes more messy and slow up website.

Comment: This is always going to be a slower way, the site has to load, be procced, and then the javascript ran, the new css file loaded and applied. Consider using media rules that apply to whole CSS files if you want to keep them sperate see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138674/different-css-files-for-different-media-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<link>` has an attribute called `media`. Here you can apply the media query to control the use of different CSS files.

```
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="xs_0.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 576px)" />
```

This is much more maintainable than using JavaScript where you need to look out for resize of window, orientation, scaleing etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of loadind differents CSS files, you can use media queries and specify css rule for each size.

```
.YourDiv {
    background-color: red;
}
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .YourDiv
        {background-color: blue;}
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .YourDiv
        {background-color: green;}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadCSS(src){
        let myCSS = document.createElement( "link" );
        myCSS.rel = "stylesheet";
        myCSS.href = src;
        // insert it at the end of the head in a legacy-friendly manner
        document.head.insertBefore( myCSS, document.head.childNodes[ document.head.childNodes.length - 1 ].nextSibling );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please explain your code, so that the person reading it may understand it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
        if (window.innerWidth < 576) {
            let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            let link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'xs_0/style.css';
            head.appendChild(link);
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 576 & window.innerWidth < 768) {
            let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            let link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 's_576/style.css';
            head.appendChild(link);
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 768 & window.innerWidth < 992) {
            let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            let link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'm_768/style.css';
            head.appendChild(link);
        } else if (window.innerWidth >= 992 & window.innerWidth < 1200) {
            let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            let link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'l_992/style.css';
            head.appendChild(link);
        } else if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
            let head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
            let link = document.createElement('link');
            link.rel = 'stylesheet';
            link.type = 'text/css';
            link.href = 'xl_1200/style.css';
            head.appendChild(link);
        } else {
            console.log("error")
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please explain your code, so that the person reading it may understand it.

Comment: Surely you can find a way to get rid of all that duplicated code... by just putting the first four lines before the start of the if/else.